# How does 你的健康都难得到保证，就更别说幸福了 work?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

From 标准教程HSK4上(p.124; nearly finished this book!):

> 当你生病了，如果由于缺钱而不能及时去看医生，**你的健康都难得到保证，就更别说幸福了**。

I translate this to:

> When you're sick, if because of lack of money [you] cannot promptly visit the doctor, **your health is not easily ensured, it's best not to say happiness**.

I'm uncomfortable with my understanding of the last part of this sentence, which seems quite different to English.

**Question**: How does 你的健康都难得到保证，就更别说幸福了 work?

To highlight my particular issues:

- Is [难得到](http://youdao.com/w/%E9%9A%BE%E5%BE%97%E5%88%B0) a set phrase?
- It seems like [保证](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BF%9D%E8%AF%81) ("guarantee") is being used as an intransitive verb, meaning something different ("ensure") than what I'm accustomed to (e.g. the guarantee of a shopkeeper).  I just want to check that I'm reading this correctly.
- I don't know what [更](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%9B%B4) is doing in this sentence.
- [别说](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%88%AB%E8%AF%B4) does not seem to mean "don't speak" here.  Is it metaphorical?

I think the intended meaning is something like

> If you fall sick and don't have money to see a doctor, you can't ensure your health, so you cannot claim to have [幸福](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%B9%B8%E7%A6%8F).

Where I'll just leave 幸福 untranslated as this nebulous notion of "happiness" and "good fortune".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"难得到" is short for "难以得到" (hard to get). It is not a standard phrase

> (連)*你的健康都难得到保证，(就)*更别说幸福了

There is a common grammar structure here:

> [連 (X) 都 (+ statement) , 更别说 (Y)了]
>
> [even (X) (+ statement) , let alone/ not to mention (Y)]
>
> [even (your health) (cannot be guaranteed/ ensured), let alone/ not to mention (your happiness)]
>
> *If your health cannot be guaranteed/ ensured , then it is even less likely that your happiness can be guaranteed*

*連 is omitted in your sentence*

*就 can be omitted in your sentence*

More example of [連 (X) 都 (+ statement) , 更别说 (Y)了] structure:

> 連(我)都打不過他, 更别说(你)了
>
> even (I) can't defeat him, let alone (you)
>
> *If I can't defeat him, it is even less likely that you can defeat him*

Answer (score 1):

Here, "就更别说" means "let alone".

"难得到" is not a set phrase. It seems to me that "得到保证" is.

"保证" is still a noun in this sentence (I confirm this with my mom, a high school Chinese teacher in China).

Answer (score 1):

**如果 由于 缺钱 而 不能 及时 去 看医生[看病]**

- If you cannot visit a doctor due to lacking of money

**你的 健康 都 难[以] 得到 保证**

- Your healthy is difficult to be guaranteed. (You cannot guarantee your healthy)
- 难以: difficult to
- 得到保证：be guaranteed

**更别说 幸福 了**

- let along happinese
- 更别说：let alone ..., literally "don't even mention"

Answer (score 1):

If you give more context, you will get a better translation.

当你生病了，
When you are sick,
如果由于缺钱而不能及时去看医生，
and you can't go to see a doctor, because you don't have any money,
你的健康都难得到保证，
even your health can't be guaranteed,
就更别说幸福了。
never mind talking about happiness.

健康都难得到保证
health even difficult get guarantee

Is 难得到 a set phrase? No.

保证 a guarantee